# Linear Optimization with Categorical Constraints

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, mathematical-optimization, pulp

I am trying to optimize a lineup of players according to the level of competition to play based on maximizing a single statistic(Points in my example below). For a given lineup, 2 players are matched up against a competition level. Here is an example of my DataFrame(This is just an example, my actual DataFrame has a lot more players than this):

```
              Comp Level    Points    Minutes Played    
Player A       Elite         10.1          22
Player A       Middle        -5            22
Player A       Low           7.2           22
Player B       Elite         0.8           20
Player B       Middle        5.6           20
Player B       Low           2.2           20          
Player C       Elite        -7.2           18
Player C       Middle        3.3           21
Player C       Low           6.6           23
Player D       Elite        -7.2           18
Player D       Middle        3.3           21
Player D       Low           6.6           23
Player E       Elite        -7.2           18
Player E       Middle        3.3           21
Player E       Low           6.6           23
Player F       Elite        -7.2           18
Player F       Middle        3.3           21
Player F       Low           6.6           23
```

The optimized lineup will maximize the total points of the entire lineup (A sum of points from each player). The constraints are:
1. You can't use the same player for more than one competition level (For example, if player A is paired against the elite level, they can't be played against the middle or low levels). 
2. Each Lineup Pair has to have a minutes played value that is within 10% of each other (For Example, Player A Could be Paired with Player B at the Elite Level but not Player C).

I'm hoping my output will look something like this:

```
Line up:
Elite: Player A and B
Middle: Player C and Player D
Low: Player E and Player F
Team Total Points: X
```

I've started by creating my DataFrame and figured on using PuLP for this optimization. The part where I am struggling with is adding my objective function, and appropriate constraints to the problem.

This is my code thus far:

```
prob = LpProblem('LineUp Optimization', LpMaximize)
players = list(data['Name'])
# print('The Players under consideration are \n' + '-'*100)
# for x in players:
#     print(x, end=',\n ')

costs = dict(zip(players, data['Points']))
comp_levels = dict(zip(players, data['Competition Level']))
Minutes = dict(zip(players, data['Minutes Played']))
ozs = dict(zip(players, data['OZS%']))

player_var = LpVariable.dicts('Players', players, 0, cat='Integer')
```

Any help/guidance on what my constraints would look like within this PuLP optimization would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you're problem correctly you need to choose a pair of players for each of the Elite, Middle and lower competition levels.

There are a number of ways you could formulate this problem. The most obvious to me would be to have sets of binary variables which indicate wheter (`1`) or not (`0`) each player is chosen for each level of competition:

```
player_var = LpVariable.dicts('player_var', (players, comp_levels), cat='Binary')
```

Your objective is to maximise total points of the included players:

```
prob += lpSum([player_var[p, l]*points[p, l] for p in players for l in comp_levels])
```

You then need to put in constraints that two players should be chosen for each level:

```
for l in comp_levels:
    prob += lpSum([player_var[p, l] for p in players]) == 2
```

And that a player can play in at most one competition level:

```
for p in players:
    prob += lpSum([player_var[p, l] for l in comp_levels]) <= 1
```

And that your 10% rule on minutes played at the chosen level for the pairing is satisfied. This last one is kind of interesting. I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this but what I've done below should work... I think.

```
for l in comp_levels:
    for p in players:
        prob += minutes[p, l]*player_var[p,l] <= 1.1*lpSum([minutes[p,l]*player_ver[other_p,l] for other_p in players if other_p != p])
```

This creates a constraints for each competition level, and for each player, however if the player is not chosen to play at the level (`player_var[p,l] == 0`) then the constraints should have no effect - term on left-hand-side will be 0.

If the player is chosen (`player_var[p,l] == 1`) then the constaint ensures that the chosen player has no more than 10% more minutes than their oponent - note the right hand sand takes a sum over all other players but only 1 of these will be non-zero.

No check is carried out to ensure the chosen player has at least 90% of the minutes of their oponent - but that case is covered when this constraint is applied to their oponent.

I'm sure someone out there can suggest a much more efficient/elegant way of doing this...

Comment: Thank you for the start on this. You grasped exactly what I'm trying to do, and I think your solution will get the job done. However, I'm getting a Key Error from the player list that I'm trying to solve. I think the error is being thrown because there are multiple instances of Player A, B, C, etc. (one for each competition level). Here is the error: "
  File "Players.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    prob += lpSum([player_var[p, l]*points[p, l] for p in players for l in comp_levels])
KeyError: ('Oliver Ekman-Larsson', 'Oliver Ekman-Larsson')"

Comment: To clarify.... I had expected that you would generate lists of `players` and `comp_levels` that had just one instance of each player/level. `numpy.unique()` applied to the player name column of your df should do the trick...

Comment: interestingly when I use np.unique(data['Name'] it throws the same error; however, the error isn't thrown until the third player it encounters.

Comment: Is your data in a pandas data frame? If so you should be able to do `data.Name.unique()`

Comment: Yes it's in a pandas data frame. The error is still thrown when I use "data.Name.unique()" Here is the beginning of my code when I import the .csv and set up the data frame: "data = pd.read_csv('Lineup(Code Ready).csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape')
data = data[['Name', 'Positions', 'Competition Level', 'EVTOI', 'OZS%', 'DF Multiplier' ]]
data.Name.unique()
data = data.loc[data['Positions'] == 'D'] "

Comment: Without a sample of data causing the problem hard to know what's going on. I suspect your data is at fault as pandas very widely used. What does `print(data.Name.head())` give you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198501/discussion-between-kevin-clark-and-kabdulla).